# Emoncms installation issue

Tags: php, shared-hosting

I'm using the stable build 9.31. Of the emoncms for home monitoring. I installed it as told by that guide: https://github.com/emoncms/emoncms/blob/stable/docs/SharedLinuxHostingInstall.md1.
It first seemed to work as I can register a new user and I can log in. but afterwards errors appear. for instance the following line: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /mnt/web022/d1/14/52274514/htdocs/emoncms/Modules/feed/feed_model.php on line 452

Does anybody know that issue? If you need further information, just ask for them, I will provide them if possible.,

Thanks in Advance!

Flo

Comment: Your PHP version is too old to be using this software. You're long overdue for an upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution.... Silly question ;-)